# CSS specificity / priority based on order in style sheet?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity, css-cascade

I had a brief look at the [CSS3 Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) but couldn't find anything how to get round this problem.   Additionally, I wasn't expecting the result from this to change when you move the CSS declarations around but it does.  Any help would be great.

```css
div.green_colour div.has_colour{
  background-color: green;
}
div.red_colour div.has_colour{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red_colour">
  <div class="green_colour">
    <div class="has_colour">
      I would like this to be green
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="green_colour">
  <div class="red_colour">
    <div class="has_colour">
      I would like this to be red
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just for reference, that’s the CSS3 Selectors spec. CSS3 is modular, so there are like 51 specs — see http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work. Like HTML5, It’s Not One Big Thing.

Comment: And I think issues relating to styles having different effects when moved around might be covered in the [“CSS Cascading and Inheritance” spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/).

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks v much for the links Paul.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `E > F` child selector as a solution to your problem as such:

```
div.green_colour > div.has_colour{
  background-color: green;
}
div.red_colour > div.has_colour{
  background-color: red;
}
```

According to this chart http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html it is compatible with all major browsers and IE 7+

There are other ways to implement the solution above (e.g. via javascript) if you are interested.

-- Edit:

I'm not 100% sure if the reason for your solution not to work is due to the fact that browsers parse CSS from right to left instead of left to right, but I assume it has something to do with it. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 'Link-' that's brilliant.  Thanks so much.   No actually I was trying to avoid the javascript and will now be able to chop out a whole load more.  Thanks so much.  And thanks for the QuirksMode link too.  Here's the [w3 spec on child-combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) though it doesn't talk about this enforcing a priority.

Comment: It has to do with the red rule being declared after the green rule. both `has_colour` elements match this rule but since the red one is the last, this one is applied. This is also why you import a `reset.css` file first and not last in the HTML head.

Comment: @Benjamin agree, however the `has_colour` is declared with an ancestor `div.green_colour` as a descendant combinator relationship shouldn't the browser check for the whole rule and not just a part of it? Hence my theory of right to left parsing.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know about the '>' or that the order or CSS declarations was important.  Now I do.  Actually, my actual problem (not the one stated above) had a slight twist in that I have the has_color div nested inside another so my final css is div.green_colour > div > div.has_colour

Comment: As Benjamin says, it has nothing to do with right-to-left parsing; it has to do with the order of declaration of equally-specific rules. Also, combinators **do not** play a part in specificity.